# Mathematica, Arg and Simplify

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers

I've got problems in using Mathematica with complex numbers. Am I doing something wrong?

Two examples:

1. ComplexExpand[(x + I y)^(1/2)]
   *yields* (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[x + I y]] +  I (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)
   Sin[1/2 Arg[x + I y]]

   and I've found no way so far to get
   a simpler result (which *does* exist!)
2. ComplexExpand[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Arg[x + I y]] + I Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[Arg[x + I y]]]
   yields the same result of the argument of ComplexExpand, while it should obviously be x + I y !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of expressions are you expecting as output?

Answer (score 5):

For the second one, remember that Mathematica can't make assumptions on your symbols, so a "number" is complex by default.

That's the reason why when you enter:

```
a = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Arg[x + I y]] + I Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[Arg[x + I y]];
ComplexExpand@a
```

you get

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Arg[x + I y]] +  I Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[Arg[x + I y]]
```

or if you enter

```
FullSimplify@a
```

you get

```
E^(I Arg[x + I y]) Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

Just because Mathematica doesn't know that X and Y are **REALS**.

But you can explicitly declare it, so Mathematica is allowed to treat them as reals numbers.

Try this:

```
a = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Cos[Arg[x + I y]] + I Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[Arg[x + I y]];
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals]
FullSimplify[a]
```

and you'll get

```
x + I y
```

Remember that resetting your $Assumptions only needs

```
$Assumptions = True
```

But in general, don't expect Mathematica will render complex numbers the way you want them...

Comment: both `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` accept a second parameter for specifying assumptions, so you don't have to change your global `$Assumptions`.  Also, by default, `ComplexExpand` treats all variables not explicitly specified as complex in its second parameter as real.

Comment: First of all, thank you Belisarius.  Mathematica 7 handbook reads as follows: 
ComplexExpand[expr]
expands expr assuming that all variables are real. 

So I expected x and y to be treated as reals without any further specification
Anyway the first expression (1.) should yield something like this:

w = (((x^2 + y^2)^(1/2) + x)/2)^(1/2) + 
   I y/(2 ((x^2 + y^2)^(1/2) + x))^(1/2);  
which is the algebraic form of the main value of (x+Iy)^(1/2)